# MPI sending an array of 128bits integer

Tags: c, mpi

I have a struct like:

```
union W128_T {
uint32_t u[4];
uint64_t u64[2];
};
struct SFMT_T {
/** the 128-bit internal state array */
w128_t state[SFMT_N];
/** index counter to the 32-bit internal state array */
int idx;
};
```

It is an implementation for pseudo-random generator, mersenne twister. I want to send an SFM_T element to all workers. I have two options.

1. Using MPI_Derived type: I create an MPI_Derived type for state array, using an MPI_Type for 128 bits. I searched and i found this page for MPI_Type: [IBM Knowledge Center-MPI Data Types](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFK3V_1.3.0/com.ibm.cluster.pe.v1r3.pe400.doc/am106_pmd.htm?lang=en). There are types for 128 floating points.  Can i use it for my data type.
2. Using a char array to store state array: I plan to create a char array of size `[SFMT_N * 16 + 2]` because 128bit variable is equal to 16 chars and `+2` indicates the `idx` variable. I am not sure how to change state array into a character array. I wrote some code for this serialization:

   ```
   typedef struct SFMT_T sfmt_t;

   char * serialize(sfmt_t* sfmt)
   {
      char buffer[SFMT_N*16+sizeof(int16_t)];
      int16_t tmp_size = 0 ;
      int8_t offset = 0;
      int i=0,j;
      tmp_size =(4*sizeof(uint32_t));
      for(i=0;i<SFMT_N;i++)
      {
         memcpy(buffer+offset,&sfmt->state[i].u, tmp_size);
         for(j=offset;j<offset+tmp_size;j++)
         {
             printf("buffer %c \n",buffer[j]);
          }
         offset += tmp_size;
      }
      memcpy(buffer+offset,&sfmt->idx,sizeof(uint16_t));

      return buffer;}


     void deserialize(char* buffer, sfmt_t* sfmt)
     {
          int16_t tmp_size,start,i ; 
          for(i=0;i<SFMT_N;i++)
          {
              start = sizeof(uint32_t)*4*i; 
              tmp_size =(4*sizeof(uint32_t));
              memcpy(sfmt->state[i].u,&buffer[start], tmp_size);}

         for(i=0;i<SFMT_N;i++)
         {
              printf("%d %d %d %d \n",sfmt->state[i].u[0],sfmt->state[i].u[1],sfmt->state[i].u[2],sfmt->state[i].u[3]);
         } }
   ```

   It doesn't give exactly what i want. What am i missing?

Also, i want to know which way can be more efficient for a distributed system.

Comment: I don't know about the MPI thing, but for sure the character array will work: this is how it's usually done sending "stuff" on a network (once you deal correctly with the endianess). Also note that sizeof(int) is almost surely not 2..

Comment: Ok thanks. as `integer` variable i want to use `int16_t` which is 16 bits. That's why i add 2,isn't that right?

Comment: I'd define the struct the `usual way' - MPI_Type_struct, with the appropriate types, using offsetof or MPI_get_address to define the displacements; and for this union type I'd just treat it as a field of 16 MPI_BYTEs.

Comment: Here is an example : http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Type_create_struct.html Good luck !

Comment: On x86 systems I'd use 4 `MPI_UINT32_T`s to represent the union type because that's most likely what the SFMT implementation uses on that architecture (each XMM register can hold 4 32-bit integers).